# Express server and react-router not behaving as expected

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am currently using react, react-router, and express. Using webpack bundling and running webpack-dev-server with webpack concurrently.

When loading the application for with no path ('http://localhost/'), react-router link redirects work fine and pages are displayed with an updated URL. When attempting to access them by specifying a path ('/login'), the dist index.html is served, but the page is blank with no errors.

**Below is my server index**

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('public')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/api', require('./routes/creation'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/login'));

app.get('*', (request, response) => {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve('dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

**and App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Styling/app.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPage from './Components/Login/LoginPage';
import ResetPage from './Components/Login/ResetPage';
import RegisterPage from './Components/Login/RegisterPage';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route path="/reset" component={ResetPage} />
          <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
          <Route component={LoginPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**Project Directory**

```
Project
 |
 +-- dist
 |   |
 |   -bundle.js
 |   -index.html
 |
 +-- public
 |  |  
 |  |-- index.html
 |    
 +-- src
 |  |  
 |  --- client /... App.js
 |  --- server /... index.js
```

I cannot figure our what is causing this, would really appreciate some help

Comment: Can you show us the complete `App.js` file?

Comment: Just updated with the complete file

Answer (score 1):

Create React App documentation says that you should use something like the following code when you need to serve Apps with Client-Side Routing.

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

 -app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 +app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });
```

[Create React App](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe this is exactly what I'm doing, just with different paths. Created edit with directory structure just in case.